# Context: Not a constant expression, error on dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I was following a udemy course but I got stuck I got this error which I don't know why it ocurres

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: const RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`onPressed: selectHandler,` this line it the problematic one.
I tried removing random keyword but i really don't know what to do.

that's the error log

```
lib/answer.dart:15:20: Error: Not a constant expression.
        onPressed: selectHandler,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/answer.dart:12:20: Error: Constant evaluation error:
      child: const RaisedButton(
                   ^
lib/answer.dart:15:20: Context: Not a constant expression.
        onPressed: selectHandler,
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't put functions inside `const` expressions, just remove the `const` keyword from:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: /* const -> Remove this const keyword */ RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler, // This is not a constant because the compiler can't assign the value at the compile time, so we can't use that in a const expression
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used **const** before **RaisedButton** when calling a **variable** inside the **onPressed** Function. Try removing the **const** keyword from the **RaisedButton**. It should work that way.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: const RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `const` from `RaisedButton` and instead make your widget `const`.

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler; // Made final

  const Answer(this.selectHandler); // const added

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton( // const removed
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {

 VoidCallback selectHandler; 
 Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      /// removed const from here
      child: RaisedButton( 
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```